# How to pass variable as file name to jmeter CSV Data set Config?

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using multiple csv files in one thread for comparision purpose.

Here first CSV Data set Config returns the file names

```
1.csv
5.csv
1000.csv
```

now I want to pass above file name to second  CSV Data set Config
`C:\\Softwares\\Installed\\jmeter-3.0\\bin\\TestData\\files\\${filename}`

Is it possible in jmeter? can any one help me to resolve the problem.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CSV Data Set Config is getting initialized **before** any JMeter Variable therefore your `${filename}` will never be resolved and you will be getting "File not found" errors.

The options are in:

1. Consider using [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function instead of CSV Data Set Config
2. Switch to JMeter Properties instead of JMeter Variables.

   - Change `${filename}` to `${__P(filename)}` (see [__P() function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) for syntax)
   - Define `filename` property. It can be done in 2 ways:

     - Via *user.properties* file. Add the next line to the file:

       ```
       filename=C:\\Softwares\\Installed\\jmeter-3.0\\bin\\TestData\\files\\1.csv
       ```

       JMeter restart will be required to pick up the property
     - Via `-J` command-line argument:

       ```
       jmeter -Jfilename=C:\Softwares\Installed\jmeter-3.0\bin\TestData\files\1.csv
       ```

     See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting, getting and overriding them

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
Actually I don’t know the list of files present at this location “C:\Softwares\Installed\jmeter-3.0\bin\TestData\files\” as I am reading the list of file using another CSV Data set Config. So 1st CSV Data set Config will give me the list of file name and now I want to read these files using second csv data set config. But in the solution you provided I need to give file names to user.property file which is not possible as I don’t know the file names. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you look into the answer a little bit closer you will see recommendation to use [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function. If you are not familiar with JMeter Functions - see [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series